# Need A Form Field To Validate From A CSV File In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, text

I have been hitting a roadblock here, I am a novice coder and a bit rusty as well. The below code works fully in a wordpress functions file but I really want to validate from a CSV file vs entering 2000 lines to validate against.

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'mobileform_custom_validation', 10, 3);
function mobileform_custom_validation($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
if($posted_field->id == 496){ //change 496 to the ID of the field to validate
if(!in_array($posted_value, array('001','002'))){ //change 001 and 002 to your allowed values
  //if it doesn't match up, add an error:
$errors['field'. $posted_field->id] = 'Please contact us.';
}
}
return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Or validate against a text file would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will get the first column of a csv file into an array:

```
$list = array_map(function ($line) { return str_getcsv($line)[0]; }, file('../path_to/your_csv_file.csv'));
```

Then you just have to use it in your test:

```
if(!in_array($posted_value, $list)){
```

Your code will then look like:

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'mobileform_custom_validation', 10, 3);
function mobileform_custom_validation($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
    if($posted_field->id == 496){
        $list = array_map(function ($line) { return str_getcsv($line)[0]; }, file('../path_to/your_csv_file.csv'));
        if(!in_array($posted_value, $list)){
            $errors['field'. $posted_field->id] = 'Please contact us.';
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

But you have to set properly the path to your csv file by replacing

```
../path_to/your_csv_file.csv
```

By the real path of your CSV file. I can't do this part for you.

Comment: I added in the second part, where exactly do I put the first part? If i place it in the functions file by itself it doesn't work?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how the code should look like. You still have to change the path of the cvs file by yourself...